# Explain how the idea of "partition" is used in the proof of lagrange's theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation, proof-theory, computer-assisted-proofs

I know partiion is a collection of subsets of $S$ that are non empty, disjoint and their union is $S$; and 
Lagrange's Theorem: If $G$ is a finite group and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then  $\lvert H\rvert$ divides $\lvert G\rvert$. Moreover, the number of distinct left (right) costs of $H$ in $G$ is $\lvert G\rvert/\lvert H\rvert$. 
can someone Explain how the idea of "partition" is used in the proof of lagrange's theorem.

Comment: If you're going to ask for a proof explanation, please provide the proof you'd like explained, not just the theorem.

Comment: the only thing that was given to us was the def. of lagrange's thm.

Comment: Well then, you're going to need to come up with a proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partition just means that you are splitting up $G$ into disjoint subsets whose union is all of $G$. In the proof of Lagrange's theorem, these disjoint subset are the (left) cosets of $H$. Moreover, each coset of $H$ has the same number of elements, namely $|H|$.

So if you have $N$ items and you divide the $N$ items up into subsets where each subset has $M$ items, then $M$ must divide $N$. Also, the number of subsets is $N/M$. In the case of groups, this gives $|H|$ divides $|G|$, and the number of cosets is $|G|/|H|$.